# Trying to add PPA repo, stuck at GPG decryption

Tags: encryption, ppa, gnupg

First off, it should be out there that there are no docs. you basically have to figure everything out yourself. And the little info there is is convoluted, cryptic. basically lazy.

I want to add software to the ubuntu/debian/mint/linux workd, specifically FAF.

On my launchpad account, I noticed there was this : 
[image: Launchpad sign the ubuntu code of conduct steps]

I figured this would come into play and I might as well start taking care of it now.

as I understand it this is actually crucial to the process of creating an publishing to a PPA.

That yellow edit button lead to here :

[image: Lanchpad three steps to singing code of conduct]

and step one led here :

[image: Lanchpad add key fingerprint]

some googling later I followed this process :

1. open "Passwords and keys"

[image: from start, open "Passwords and keys"]

2. select "GnuPG keys"

[image: sidebar menu, select "GnuPG keys"]

3. click the "+"

[image: add button]

4. select "PGP Key"

[image: select "PGP Key"]

5. filled it out like so :

[image: filled out PGP creation form with expiration date set to two years and RSA and key strength of 3072]
[image: entered and confirmed passwords]

which left me with this :

[image: a newly created personal PGP key]

6. I then opened up "edit" -> "preferences" and changed it's settings to upload keys instead of not uploading keys. I also ticked the two boxes below :

[image: edited preferences to upload keys to hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371]

7. I then went into "Remote" -> "Sync and publish keys...", and clicked on "Sync"

[image: one key is selected for synchronizing]

8. I then waited 5-10 minutes
9. then on the launchpad site I entered my key's fingerprint found by right-clicking on your key then opening it's properties then going to the details tab :

[image: details tab of my key]

after clicking "import" on the launchpad site, there was a blue box stating that I received an email with confirmation link to be decrypted :

[image: check email and click decrypted link]

I went to my mail, I should mention I use webmail, specifically hotmail.

I found the mail in my unwanted bin and moved it to trusted senders and opened it and indeed the mail features a chuck of encrypted data.

I tried decrypting it by saving the chunk to a file called file.txt and in terminal using :

```
gpg --decrypt --force-mdc --no-mdc-warning file.txt
```

but I am met with

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error
```

Is my attempt to decrypt it the right method?

how do I decrypt this message?

Keys and Passwords doesn't seem to provide a means to do so.

Comment: Firstly there are docs, though I don't recall Ubuntu ones, but they did have pointers to the upstream docs.  I recall going to the GNU Privacy Guard docs (GPG) which I thought were pretty good. I recall saving the encrypted text to a file, and using the command the docs provided as example changing only the keyfile & file.to.decrypt on my command from example of GPG upstream docs. I also believe the `man` pages were enough once you'd saved it to a file, and just try and use commands to decrypt a 'file' (containingmessage itself, or at least encrypted part with its header/footer still intact)

Comment: Have a look at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=680292  (specifically decrypt a file).  The doc page I found most helpful was https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto  (I think, it was a few months ago i had to re-authorize something on lp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :

as it happens the

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
```

and

```
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

are actually wanted in the block that you translate.

so copy the whole block received in your email :

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

*********************************/****************************
*******/********************************************/*********
 *****/********************************** 
 *****/*/************
=****
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

save it to a file :

```
file.gpg
```

then in terminal :

```
gpg --decrypt file.gpg
```

you'll have to type in the password you selected when creating the key, then you'll get an output ending in :

```
Please go here to finish adding the key to your Launchpad account:

    https://launchpad.net/token/*****************
```

copy the link and paste it into your favorite web browser, you'll then be asked to confirm the adding of this key to your account, select "confirm", and you'll be greeted wit this message :

[image: the key was successfully added]